# indexing logs for fast repeated grep/search

Tags: grep

I have sets of verbose logfiles that in the course of solving a problem, I will repeatedly regrep.

I usually have about 1-10GB sets of 50-150 files, that I'll spend a few hours with and then never look at again.

Even with an SSD and lots of RAM it can take a few dozens of seconds to get results. It also only pegs 1 core, so if it could search in parallel, that would be good too.

I'm wondering if I can do any better by indexing in some way. It would be nice to spend a few minutes up front to have better performance later.

Preferably it would be something I can run at the terminal in the directory, and have an interface like grep. Then at the end I can delete the folder entirely and that will also delete the index.

Does this sound possible, and does something exist? What's my next best option?

Comment: Best I can suggest is anytime to run grep on a file [or set of], send the output to a new file and do further narrowing on that smaller 'pre-grepped' file.

Comment: Are you searching for different results each time or are you re-using older queries and grabbing new data with it?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66297/22470

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably more complicated than you are willing to set up, given your *requirements*, such that they are.

Use a logging aggregation stack that can read/tail the files for you ( [fluend](http://fluentd.org/), index them [Elastic Search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) and present a pretty interface [Kibana](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/kibana/) for you.

Just configure it to delete them as often as you like.

*this is only one solution stack, check out [logstash](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/logstash/) as well as many others*